# PrestaShop main page doesen't work after moving to localhost

Tags: localhost, prestashop

I've got problem after moving my website on localhost. I've setted up everything, admin page works well but when i want to visit index page appears an error:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of FrontController::displayHeader() should be compatible with FrontControllerCore::displayHeader($display = true) in C:\xampp\htdocs\altrak\override\classes\FrontController.php on line 16 [Debug] This page has moved
```

Searching for solution for hours and nothing found. Any ideas?

Turned off "_PS_MODE_DEV_" to false in defines.inc.php and then getting an http error 500

Answer (score 0):

You error message says you have an override for FrontController in \override\classes\FrontController.php where the function `displayHeader()` should be `displayHeader($display = true)` instead.
Check that file, and change it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change all original domain.name in your database,

open "yourdbfile.sql" file, search and replace all "domainname.ltd" with "localhost" domain.

but properly PrestaShop admin directory working, before change it.